# Iphone push notification in Joomla

Tags: notifications, push, joomla3.0

I m Doing Iphone/Android push notification in joomla using Zend library it is working properly in Core php but it shows error in joomla when submitting a form LIKE  :

**

> An error has occurred while processing your request. You may not be
> able to visit this page because of: an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
> a mistyped address a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for
> this site you have no access to this page Home Page If difficulties
> persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and
> report the error below.
>
> ## 0 "Zend_Uri_Http" not found Powered by    Joomla!®

**

If there is any way to resolve this error plz. let me khow the help will be appriciated...
Thanks in advance.
Amit Raval

Comment: Please refer this link:http://my-sliit.blogspot.in/2010/08/fatal-error-class-zendurihttp-zendgdata.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set path as per your current location of directory

suppose if you are in component/controllers direcotory

use like:

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'controllers/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');
```

It must be done throughout all zend files to solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: and it is especially for Joomla!

Answer (score 3):

NOT FOUND error occurs when your include file is not loaded. try to include ZEND LIBRARY FILE which loads "ZEND_URI_HTTP" file...

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');
```